# Errors in compiling boost:thread in Windows Eclipse C++ plugin

Tags: c++

I can get other boost libraries to work in Eclipse C++ plugin, but have problem in boost thread. What's the problem?

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void hello()
{
   cout<<"hello world!"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    boost::thread thrd(&hello);
    cout<<"Just a test!"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Error messages:
**** Rebuild of configuration Debug for project Hello ****

Internal Builder is used for build               **

```
g++ -IC:\boost_1_47_0 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -osrc\hello.o ..\src\hello.cpp
In file included from C:\boost_1_47_0/boost/thread/win32/thread_data.hpp:12,
                 from C:\boost_1_47_0/boost/thread/thread.hpp:15,
                 from ..\src\hello.cpp:1:
C:\boost_1_47_0/boost/thread/win32/thread_heap_alloc.hpp:59: warning: inline function 'void* boost::detail::allocate_raw_heap_memory(unsigned int)' declared as  dllimport: attribute ignored
C:\boost_1_47_0/boost/thread/win32/thread_heap_alloc.hpp:69: warning: inline function 'void boost::detail::free_raw_heap_memory(void*)' declared as  dllimport: attribute ignored
g++ -LC:\boost_1_47_0\stage\lib -oHello.exe src\hello.o -lboost_filesystem-mgw46-mt-d-1_47 -lboost_regex-mgw46-mt-1_47 -lboost_system-mgw46-mt-1_47 -lboost_thread-mgw46-mt-1_47 -lboost_date_time-mgw46-mt-1_47
src\hello.o: In function `main':
C:\Users\cmin\workspace\Hello\Debug/../src/hello.cpp:15: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5boost6threadD1Ev'
C:\Users\cmin\workspace\Hello\Debug/../src/hello.cpp:15: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5boost6threadD1Ev'
src\hello.o: In function `thread<void (*)()>':
C:/boost_1_47_0/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:204: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5boost6thread12start_threadEv'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Build error occurred, build is stopped
Time consumed: 1044  ms.
```